# Installing docker 17 version on centos 7

Tags: docker

I want install docker 17 on centos,can you please suggest me on this.
once i have used below yum command to install docker 
yum install docker* 
I got 1.12.6 version.

Answer (score 2):

The 1.12.6 version you have installed is a package that is maintained by Red Hat / CentOS.

To install the official Docker package, that is maintained by Docker, follow the instructions in the documentation; https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/

Be sure to uninstall the package you have installed before installing the official package.

Answer (score 0):

You're installing last Docker version that is in your CentOS repos.

To install last Docker stable version, first, uninstall your current Docker installation. Then, you can easily install last version using Docker official installation script.

`wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

Comment: Thank you ...with above command ....It got installed docker 17 version...Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:06:25 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

Comment: And also can you please  suggest me how to install docker-compose for the corresponding docker 17 version.

Comment: Use the instructions for the last release: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases.

Comment: looks like 1.13 is the latest docker-compose version and no where mentioned about docker Version: 17.05.0-ce API compatibility.can you please clarify on this.

Comment: In that link you have a "Compose file format compatibility matrix", where you can see compatibility between Compose file format and Docker Engine version. Docker Engine 17.05 is compatible with all docker-compose version, since all Docker Engine maintain backwards compatibility with old Compose versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick responses ..In the compatibility matrix  I am not seeing Docker Engine 17.05  version.so I got doubt.

Comment: It said 1.13.0+, which means any version superior to 1.13.0. Please, accept the answer if it was helpful to you :)

Comment: Thanks you kstromeiraos